# AS400 SQL - Select records from a file where there are unique values based on the grouping of another column

Tags: sql, database, ibm-midrange

Calling all AS400 SQL gurus-
Imagine you have a database as such

| Client | DATA 1 |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 |
| ABC | 123 |
| ABC | 123 |
| EFG | 456 |
| LMN | 678 |
| QRS | 555 |
| QRS | 556 |
| XYZ | 789 |
| XYZ | 789 |
| XYZ | 999 |

I'm seeking an SQL solution that will group the Client field and inspect DATA 1 and identify all instances where any DATA 1 differs within a specific client. So for example -
-Client ABC - all of DATA 1 for client ABC are identical so do NOT select.
-Client EFG - A single so DATA 1 will ALWAYS match so do NOT select.
-Client LMN -  A single so DATA 1 will ALWAYS match so do NOT select.
-Client QRS- 2 records and the DATA 1 records do not match -Include all in the SQL selection
-Client XYZ - 2 records are identical but a single record does not match - Include all in the SQL selection.

So in the end my SQL selection should look like -

| Client | DATA 1 |
| --- | --- |
| QRS | 555 |
| QRS | 556 |
| XYZ | 789 |
| XYZ | 789 |
| XYZ | 999 |

That is to say- I have a listing of all records where DATA 1 is NOT identical within a Client grouping.

FWIW - I've tested UNIQUE, GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT, etc.....and I still find myself stuck.
Thanks in advance for any and all of your help.

FWIW - I've tested UNIQUE, GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT, etc.....and I still find myself stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a CTE or sub-query to get the clients which have more than one distinct data_1 value.

```
select *
  from table1
where client in (
  select client
    from table1
  group by client
  having count(distinct data_1) > 1
  ) --alias if needed
```